# How to disable the hardware camera so OS do not detect it

Tags: android, camera

I need to test an application where OS fails to detect the camera and my application is still able to proceed without capturing the image.

Please note: I want to disable the hardware so that OS do not detects/identifies problem with Camera.

I tried to disable the camera using apps available in the play store but even after installing them., OS detects the hardware of camera, so my purpose is not solved.

Answer (score 0):

Using Eclipse as development environment, I would try to set-up a new emulated device. As you may know you can set a lot of hardware settings, like memory, screen size, and the presence of the camera.

[image]

As you can see you can specify both front and rear camera. Options are:

- None
- Emulated
- Webcam0 (linux device)